# Chrome + Vimeo autoplay video with audio on button click

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, vimeo, playback

does anyone have any idea why this does not the trigger the playback on first page visit? (view on incog)

The user needs to click the button to trigger this so as far as I know this should work. As a side note, this works on firefox without any problems at all.

The issue exists on chromium based browsers which I had a similar situation on microsoft edge. Is this chrome specific or vimeo? I've tried a similar approach using a different hosting platform like youtube and it does work.

This weird combination of vimeo and chrome is an exception.

I've attached a link for ease of demonstration.

codepen.io/Rich-Philben-Cuer/pen/gOZPzej